# javascript code works individually but fails when used on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

each of the 3 code snippets '`on.change();`' below work individually, but appears to fail when they are all brought onto the same page. I think this has something to do with the '`this.checked`' area - it seems this only reads the last one `elem3` any suggestions would be amazing. *Seeking JS not jQuery.*

```
var elem = document.getElementById('item1'),
    checkBox = document.getElementById('check1');

checkBox.checked = false;
checkBox.onchange = function () {
    elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.getElementById("item2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("item3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("item4").style.display = "none";
};
checkBox.onchange();


var elem2 = document.getElementById('item2'),
    checkBox2 = document.getElementById('check2');

checkBox2.checked = false;
checkBox2.onchange = function () {
    elem2.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.getElementById("item1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("item3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("item4").style.display = "none";
};
checkBox2.onchange();


var elem3 = document.getElementById('item3'),
    checkBox3 = document.getElementById('check3');

checkBox3.checked = false;
checkBox3.onchange = function () {
    elem3.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.getElementById("item1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("item2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("item4").style.display = "none";
};
checkBox3.onchange();
```

the HTML is below; what is supposed to occur is only divs in relation to the checkboxs should show when a checkbox is selected. So if the first checkbox is selected on, that checkbox and it's wrapper should show, if all 4 are checked, these 4 should show. 2, 3 etc. The ones that are not selected should hide. *Again my JS code works individually, but when I want to do all on that same page, they fail.*

HTML

```
  <div class="container" id="records" style="background-color:#fff">
        <br/>
        <div class="row" id="item1">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class=jumbotron>
                    <h1>Item 1!</h1>
                    <p>Item 1 Details for the PDF test.</p>
<!--                     <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=# role=button>Learn more</a></p>
 -->                
                     <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="sample[]"/> This is a checkbox1</label>
                     <br />

                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="item2">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class=jumbotron>
                    <h1>Item 2!</h1>
                    <p>Item 2 Details for the PDF test.</p>
<!--                     <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=# role=button>Learn more</a></p>
 -->                

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="sample[]"/> This is a checkbox1</label><br />

                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="item3">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class=jumbotron>
                    <h1>Item 3!</h1>
                    <p>Item 3 Details for the PDF test.</p>
<!--                     <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=# role=button>Learn more</a></p>
 -->                

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="sample[]"/> This is a checkbox1</label><br />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="item4">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class=jumbotron>
                    <h1>Item 4!</h1>
                    <p>Item 4 I'm a hidden div!</p>
<!--                     <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=# role=button>Learn more</a></p>
 -->                
                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="sample[]"/> This is a checkbox1</label><br />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg download-pdf" href="#" role=button>Download PDF</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML-Code? Or a JSFiddle? Can't see an issue here right now

Comment: I mean the mark-up is just HTML divs with check boxes.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion this is to do with ID reuse, but I could confirm with a view of your HTML. You can do some basic things to anonymize it if you want.

Comment: I'd like to try the code to find the error. Try `alert(this.id)` in `onchange` please

Comment: [I don't see any errors on the console](https://jsfiddle.net/wz5sxehn/).

Comment: @CodeiSir it just says undefined

Comment: That's bad ;) It should be 'check3', shouldn't it?

Comment: what is an alternative to using 'this' I had  feeling it was that.

Comment: Is my answer working for you?

Comment: You are missing the opening tag for `This is a checkbox1</label>`

Comment: Thanks, but that does not effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you question is still unclear, and I will update the answer. But if it is working correctly as in John Bupit's https://jsfiddle.net/wz5sxehn/ - your problem is a simple logical error, not a code error.

Is this JSFiddle working the same as your code?

The problem is you are doing this for every element:

```
elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
document.getElementById("item2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("item3").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("item4").style.display = "none";
```

For every check-box. One will then hide the other while unhiding itself!

See this running as you want to with minimal changes to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/wz5sxehn/3/

With your HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/wz5sxehn/6/

Comment: I get what your saying, but all functionality dies with this suggestion. I think it's something to do with using 'this.checked' at multiple instances. Anyone have an alternative to this?

Comment: `all functionality dies with this suggestion` - did you try it, I think I am right? `this.checked` is fine dude ;)

Comment: The checkboxes are in the "items" what are you trying to achieve? :(

Comment: @YourConscious: https://jsfiddle.net/wz5sxehn/5/ your HTML with my modified JS, is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort. But the checkboxs that are selected / checked are only supposed to show and the one(s) that are not selected are supposed to be hidden.

Comment: Sir, you can not check the checkboxes inside the hidden element :D They are not aviable to be checked

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your requirements are not crystal clear. Still, I think this code does what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/6g0ows2g/

```
var elem = document.getElementById('item1'),
    checkBox = document.getElementById('check1'),
    elem2 = document.getElementById('item2'),
    checkBox2 = document.getElementById('check2'),
    elem3 = document.getElementById('item3'),
    checkBox3 = document.getElementById('check3'),
    elem4 = document.getElementById('item4'),
    checkBox4 = document.getElementById('check4');

function updateOptions() {
    document.getElementById("item1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("item2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("item3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("item4").style.display = "block";
}

function toggleBlocks(elem, checkBox) {
    updateOptions();
    checkBox.checked = false;
    elem.style.display = "none";
}

checkBox.onchange = function () {
    toggleBlocks(elem, checkBox); 
};

checkBox2.onchange = function () {
    toggleBlocks(elem2, checkBox2); 
};

checkBox3.onchange = function () {
    toggleBlocks(elem3, checkBox3); 
};

checkBox4.onchange = function () {
    toggleBlocks(elem4, checkBox4); 
};
```

As a side note, whenever you find yourself repeating a lot of similar code, group that code into a function and use parameters. I find it helps in removing the clutter that hides syntax errors and logic errors.

updateOptions() can be made more elegant, but I'll leave that up to you. Remember, make it work, make it right, make it fast.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with your code.
As you asked, I've put the 3 code snippets together on the same page and it worked the way it seems to me it was meant to be in your proposal..

The page is always loaded with 'Item-3' visible, because the 'checkBox3.onchange' initiates the elements this way overwriting any previous configuration made by previous 'onchanges'.
(i.e: and at the end of the script 'checkBox3' is configured as unchecked and the item3 as display=block which makes it visible).

if you want to hide item-3 on the page load just uncomment the last line:

```
 //onload (document.getElementById("item3").style.display = "none");
```

AFAIK, we should avoid mixing javascript and html this way.
Anyway here it goes the code... 
I hope it helps (tested on firefox)

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html><head><title>Javascript Test</title>
        </head>
        <body> <h3>Checkbox test</h3>
        <form name="CheckBoxes">
              <label for="check1">Checkbox 1</label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="check1" Id="check1" tabindex="1"><br><br><br>
              <label for="check2">Checkbox 2</label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="check2" Id="check2" tabindex="2"><br><br><br>       
              <label for="check3">Checkbox 3</label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="check3" Id="check3" tabindex="3"><br><br><br>    
        </form>

        <p id="item1"> Item-1</p><p id="item2"> Item-2</p><p id="item3"> Item-3</p><p id="item4"> Item-4</p>



        <script language="javascript">

        var elem = document.getElementById('item1'),
            // var elem2 = document.getElementById('item2'),

            checkBox = document.getElementById('check1');
        checkBox.checked = false;
        checkBox.onchange = function () {
            elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
            document.getElementById("item2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("item3").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("item4").style.display = "none";

        };
        checkBox.onchange();


        var elem2 = document.getElementById('item2'),
            // var elem2 = document.getElementById('item2'),

            checkBox2 = document.getElementById('check2');
        checkBox2.checked = false;
        checkBox2.onchange = function () {
            elem2.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
            document.getElementById("item1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("item3").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("item4").style.display = "none";

        };
        checkBox2.onchange(); 

        var elem3 = document.getElementById('item3'),
            // var elem2 = document.getElementById('item2'),

    checkBox3 = document.getElementById('check3');
checkBox3.checked = false;
checkBox3.onchange = function () {
    elem3.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.getElementById("item1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("item2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("item4").style.display = "none";

};
checkBox3.onchange();
 //onload (document.getElementById("item3").style.display = "none");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```